# C++: conjunction of binds?

Tags: c++, boost, bind

Suppose the following two functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> // atoi
#include <cstring> // strcmp
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

bool match1(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return (strcmp(a, b) == 0);
}

bool match2(int a, const char* b) {
    return (atoi(b) == a);
}
```

Each of these functions takes two arguments, but can be transformed into a callable object that takes only one argument by using (std/boost)`bind`. Something along the lines of:

```
boost::bind(match1, "a test");
boost::bind(match2, 42);
```

I want to be able to **obtain, from two functions like these that take one argument and return `bool`, a callable object that takes two arguments and returns the && of the `bool`s**. The type of the arguments is arbitrary.

Something like an `operator&&` for functions that return `bool`.

Comment: Don't you want a function that takes one argument and returns a bool ? Ie equivalent to `match1("a test", X) && match2(42, X)` ? or do you really want `match1("a test", X) && match2(42, Y)` ?

Comment: I really want a function that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return type of `boost::bind` overloads `operator &&` (as well as [many others](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators)). So you can write

```
boost::bind(match1, "a test", _1) && boost::bind(match2, 42, _2);
```

If you want to store this value, use [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/function.html). In this case, the type would be

```
boost::function<bool(const char *, const char *)>
```

Note that this isn't the return type of `boost::bind` (that is unspecified), but any functor with the right signature is convertible to a `boost::function`.

Comment: Can I have a function that returns something of type of `boost:bind`?

Comment: It works http://gist.github.com/367475 (btw, why `_1` and `_2` are in global namespace?)

Comment: @Sebastian, because it makes it easier to work with? (FYI, they're in an unnamed namespace defined in `boost/bind/placeholders.hpp`.)

Comment: @Jesse Beder: Lambda uses boost::lambda and Phoenix uses boost::spirit namespace for placeholders, so It is unclear why the Bind library should be any different.

Comment: @Sebastian, it seems to be a popular question. I found this conversation on the boost mailing list: http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/06/48805.php that links to a ticket, but it doesn't look like anything's being done about it. And it seems that `std::bind`'s placeholders will be in `std::placeholder`.